# Using PHP and Regex to extract Paypal Button ID

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have the following Paypal "Add to Cart" HTML button code:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DJ445KDUWP402">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0"   name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Using PHP and regular expressions, could anyone tell me how I could get just the value portion of the "hosted_button_id" input?

Thanks!

Comment: why use a regex? an XML parser like SimpleXML http://ca2.php.net/SimpleXML would be much more robust.

Comment: If he doesn't need something more robust, why use something more robust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="([0-9-A-Z]*?)">~', $html, $matches)
$matches[1]; //contains ID
```

should do the trick

Comment: wouldn't $matches[1] contain the ID?

Comment: Yup, I just had to echo $matches[1] to get the value I was after.

Answer (score 0):

This will work and is very flexible. All it requires is that the `value` attribute appears after the `name` attribute in the `hosted_button_id` element. The `s` and `m` modifiers will allow you to match over multiple lines. So you can in essence match against the entire html page rather than just the `hosted_button_id` element.

```
$str = '<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DJ445KDUWP402">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0"   name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>';

preg_match('/name="hosted_button_id".*?value="(.*?)".*?>/ims', $str, $matches);
```

The output of this is as expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name="hosted_button_id" value="DJ445KDUWP402">
    [1] => DJ445KDUWP402
)
```

You can take this approach one step further and match all input elements names and their values.

```
preg_match_all('/<input .*?name="(.*?)" .*?value="(.*?)".*?>/ims', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            [1] => <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DJ445KDUWP402">
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => cmd
            [1] => hosted_button_id
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => _s-xclick
            [1] => DJ445KDUWP402
        )
)
```

Comment: you don't grab the ID to an array

Comment: He's after the value not the ID